Youtube Analytics API mimic Youtube reporting api channel_basic_a2
I am attempting to mimic the Youtube bulk reporting api with the Youtube Ananlytics api for a data pipeline. I was curious if anyone had done that successfully before, I am having issues pulling all the data in one go which may or may not be possible.
Tried Pulling a specific video data, but not able to pull multiple. Maybe I do have to pull individual though and then combine them.

Specify the exact issues you're facing with the Youtube Analytics API. Are there errors or limitations?
